# Add script into AOSP

Tags: android, makefile, compilation, android-source

I wanted to add a script file `.sh` file to root (/) directory in `AOSP`. I would like to have my script file available in that location.

So I basically added my .sh file in android/build/target/product folder and correspondingly added the following lines in the make file full.mk

`PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/batteryless.sh:/batteryless.sh`

But after the compilation finish I can't see the file in `android/out/target/product/MY_PRODUCT/root` and after flash images the file isn't there.

I'm I missing something? I just want to include this script into `AOSP`. Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: Is it mandatory to be there? Usually these kinds of things would go to /system/bin/.
Does it work if you put it in  /system/bin/ ?

Comment: Not actually, it can be in any directory, I just want the file inside AOSP when I flash images. Can you tell me how can I put in /system/bin?

Comment: PRODUCT_COPY_FILES is the way to go. It's likely you're putting it in a wrong makefile, and its not getting evaluated.
Try to add it in the device/............/YOUR_DEVICE.mk, so it's for sure included

Comment: Here's a snippet from my makefile that works, for comparison:

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += 
    device/rockchip/rk3399/uart_test_app:system/bin/uart_test_app

Comment: It worked! Thank you @RickSanchez for the support